# Faking SerialPort Communication

Tags: unit-testing, automation, serial-port, travis-ci

I am looking to mock a Serial Port so I can test communication and OS flushing.

Things I am hoping for out of the mock serial port. (in order of importance to the project)

- Pass [istty](http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/c/lib/istty.html)
- Able to be used with an automated test suite (no gui)
- Language Agnostic
- Able to run on TravisCI
- Cross Platform

I don't know if all those options are possible. But doing so would be nice.  I know Unix treats everything as a file, so if I could just create a file that passes [istty](http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/c/lib/istty.html), that would be a good solution, but probably not windows compatible.

Anyway any ideas for testing SerialPort communication would be amazing.

Thanks Everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you use CMock you can pass a .h file and get a mock generated.

Failing that, I'd write one by hand. Nothing fancy, just the stubs and some basic known return values. Once the mock (and your tests/unit under test) is sufficiently developed, that's when I'd switch to an integration test with the real socket API

Comment: The problem with integration testing the real socket API is an integration test would require connected hardware.  Everything above this level is passed a mock that responds to the correct interface, but because the lowest level isn't tested a bug with buffering was not caught.